# how to write a function for shift without splice

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I've been trying to write functions for some basic array methods but am stuck now on re-creating shift without using splice. Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
MyShift = function (array) {
    for (i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
    }
    --array.length;
};
```

Comment: What do you mean by `shift` ?
Can you provide `input` array and `expected` array ?

Comment: you mean this function? [Array.shift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)?

Comment: Sliding all the elements down in a loop like you are already doing should work if you start at the beginning of the array rather than looping through backwards. Though  you'd need to save the value of the original first element and return it from your function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of how you are iterating, you are changing the value at `i` with `i+1` then is moving backward, so you are assigning the last value to all positions

```js
MyShift = function(array) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) {
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
  };
  --array.length;
};

var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
MyShift(a);
document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(a))
```

In the above case, when you loop at first iteration you have `i=1`, so you have `array[1] = array[2]`, so the array becomes `[a, c, c]`, then next `i=0` so you have `array[0] = array[1]`, but since the previous iteration already updated the value of `arra[1]` you will have `[c,c,c]`

```js
MyShift = function(array) {
  snippet.log('src: ' + array)
  for (i = array.length - 2; i >= 0; i--) {
    array[i] = array[i + 1];
    snippet.log('loop ' + i + ': ' + array);
  }
  --array.length;
};

var a = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
MyShift(a);
snippet.log('Result: ' + a)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Ah yes, that makes sense. This has been very frustrating, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `Array.prototype.shift()` method.

This method removes the first element from an array and returns that element. This method changes the length of the array.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift

Comment: Looks like they want to re-create a `shift()` method themselves.

Comment: Probably this question should then be asked in Code Review

Comment: Because it is more about algorithms than the usage of programming languages.

Comment: @CharlieH on Code Review the code in question needs to work. Broken code is **off topic**.

Comment: Oh ok. I didn't know that. And Code View sounds super cool to me now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can make something like this.

```
MyShift = function (array) {
    for (i =0; i<array.length; i++) {
        array[i] = array[i + 1];
        console.log(array[i]);
    }
    --array.length;
    return(array);
}; 
MyShift([1,2,3,4]);
```

Hope it will help